# Keep getting "tsc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

As soon as I add a tsconfig.json file to my Visual Studio 2015 web solution I get the above error.

Also this stops the compiler from re-generating js files even when I set "compileOnSave": true.

When I double click the error it takes me into the Microsoft.Typescript.Targets file which contains a lot of issues such as Unknown Item Group "TypeScriptCompile". In the error list these appear as warnings but they are there whether I have a tsconfig.json file or not.

Is there any way of solving it or getting more information on what the problem is?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Install these 2 NuGet packages:

**Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild** and **Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler**

It updates your project with MSBuild task definition and TS compiler and solves the compilation issue

Comment: Thanks. The error has gone. Compile on save is not working but that's probably something different.

Comment: you saved me after a long journey through stackoverflow

Comment: Do not work for me, I still get the same exact error

Comment: Installing just Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild worked for me. Good solution!

Comment: Thanks. Getting Visual Studio and TypeScript to play nicely with each other is more difficult than it really should be!

Comment: At least in ASP.Net Core it works pretty fine without these packages now (October 2016) (I think it will for ordinary ASP.Net as well), you can just update the version of the extension, please see my answer below (http://stackoverflow.com/a/40328662/1671558)

Comment: after installing "Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" I get this error:
The "OutputLogFile" parameter is not supported by the "VsTsc" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property. 
The "VsTsc" task could not be initialized with its input parameters.
Second package installation does nothing.

Comment: Its solved by installing `TypeScript 2.0.6 for 2015` from Visual Studio menu `Tools->Extensions and Updates`

Comment: Here is a link to the installer https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593

Comment: if this dont work, you should delete all content in "obj" folder and restart visual studio

Comment: I had some missing cs files included in my project, once I deleted them the tsc error went away.

Comment: My typescript project has the "manage nuget packages" option greyed out and inaccessible.
ahmadalibaloch suggested above:
Its solved by installing TypeScript 2.0.6 for 2015 from Visual Studio menu Tools->Extensions and Updates. I picked 2.2.1 which matches my Node.js installation and it worked.

Comment: I faced an error while installing it in the above sequence. First, install Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and then Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild

Comment: First, launch Visual Studio as administrator, then install these packeges.

Answer (score 60):

For me installing [TypeScript for Visual Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) fixed it, although TypeScript was already installed globally on my machine via `npm`

Comment: I needed to install this and 2 nuget packages mentioned in other answer as well to make VS2015 happy.

Comment: This is what worked for me. The other changes didn't help until I installed the latest version of TS for VS.

Comment: Yes, getting the latest Typescript for VS 2015 (2.2.2.0 right now) fixed the problem for me also

Answer (score 45):

I am using a .NET Core 1.0 project and ran into the same situation of getting a `tsc.exe` return code of 1. My problem was an invalid `tsconfig.json`. However, msbuild does not provide those details.

The easiest way to find out is to enable detailed output in `Visual Studio -> Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run -> MSBuild project build output verbosity`. Change this to `Detailed`. After compiling, find `tsc.exe` in the output window to see the actual error tsc was throwing.

Comment: +1 After changing verbosity to detailed I found the message `TS6046:Build:Argument for '--module' option must be 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', or 'es6'`. Right clicked on the project and selected `Properties > TypeScript Build` and changed to `CommonJS` under `Module System` and everything started working again.

Comment: Thank you for describing how to diagnose the problem. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @David I agree. As far as it seems, anything could be `code 1`

Comment: I agree also. This led me to error 'Unknown compiler option 'listemittedfiles'' and an SO fix.

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem as well after using some standard Angular / Typescript tutorials. The solution was as simple as to update typescript in Visual Studio.

For some reason the default is now 1.8.4. and it does not allow you to automatically update it from Visual Studio Extensions and does not say it is out of date. You just download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593) and install newest version yourself. Download link may change in the future of course.

P.S. I think the problem was caused by the fact that some options that did not exist in older compiler were used.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for TeamCity build server with Visual Studio 2015 when I had upgraded a project from Typescript `1.8` to `2.3`

- Install package `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`
- Update `*.csproj` as follows

  1. Upgrade `TypeScriptToolsVersion` to `2.3` (in this case)
  2. Remove two lines of `Import Project` that referred to 
     `Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets`

#### Note

- Removing the `import` elements is important as they are referring to TypeScript installed in the `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%` folder.
- Installing the package adds `import` elements that reference the `packages` folder - making your build more portable

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue and what happened in my case is that the file .ts was in the project but it was not on file system. Something like this [image: missing file on filesystem]. So removed the file from project and everything started to work again.

Comment: This was my solution, too.  In my case, a coworker who uses TypeScript often made a change to some files and caused a reference to a *.ts file to be left in the project file.  This should be the right answer for those who Google the error and find themselves here but aren't using TypeScript in their project.

Answer (score 2):

Move all files within `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Typ‌​escript` into some new folder (e.g. `backup`), then try again. This will cause MSBuild to select `tsc.exe` from within the appropriately versioned folder instead of using the one in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript`.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Microsoft.Typescript.MsBuild fixed the issue for me, but only if I installed the penultimate version. The current (stable) version is 2.0.6, and after I installed it, the issue persisted. When I reverted to 1.8.11, the issue went away.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by removing the following from the project file

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>2.0</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

Comment: I fixed mine similarly ...edited the .csproj file but changed the version of TypeScript to 1.8 (which is what I had installed). It needs to match what you have installed on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking on one of the `.ts` files inside of visual studio worked for me. It then came up with a dialog box asking if I wanted to update the project to the latest version of TS. After that the project built fine and the compile error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

There is need to Re-Install/Upgrade, Typescript in your system.

As i was facing same issue and after installing Typescript again got resolved the error, as **tsc.exe was missing** in (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\2.1).

Answer (score 0):

We are using `npm` and `angular-cli` outside VS to transpile our typescript. I ran into the problem described above on the only dev box that had the Web Essentials extension loaded. After trying installing, and then uninstalling the MS nugets and TypeScript extension described above to no avail, uninstalling Web Essentials finally did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, and the reason was, 2 developers were working on same project so when he added new .ts files into project and some angular controllers. The project was rebuilding and running as expected however when another developer tried to take latest source code on his machine and on rebuilding he was getting same error "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.
**So reason was the files created/added in source control was not showing added on 
 developer 2 solution. Please try to check if all the .ts, .js files are up to date on both developers solution.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a solution using AngularJS but without the compiler (below 2.x so not needed). I simply removed the index.d.ts from script folder and it was ok (no NuGet packages necessary)

Answer (score 0):

If youre are facing this problem when updating from bootstrap 3 to 4 just delete .ts file created inside the Scripts Folder then build again.