# VS2013 TypeScript error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, msbuild

I have a Web Project with some typescript files but suddenly I started receiving this error message:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(95,5): error MSB6006: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1.
>   1>
>   1>Build FAILED.

I have no idea why this started. Please Help

Comment: Remove unnecessary npm packages under your npm reference directory.

Answer (score 1):

## This question is solved in...

### See these posts:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41053281/1780318

["tsc.exe" exited with code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181699/tsc-exe-exited-with-code-1)

["tsc.exe" exited with code 1 when using ASP.net 4 MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625035/tsc-exe-exited-with-code-1-when-using-asp-net-4-mvc/41053281#41053281)

Comment: Instead of providing links, Please answer the question in detail.