# Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --out error in visual studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I want to combine Angularjs and TypeScript in a asp.net web api, so I try this blog post: [LINK](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.fr/2014/07/angularjs-typescript-setting-up-basic.html)

when I run my application I encounter whit this error:

**Error Build:Only 'amd' and 'system' modules are supported alongside --out.**

I tried this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37350183/keep-getting-tsc-exe-exited-with-code-1) and install both of *Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild* and *Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler*, but it still stops with that error.

so I try this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963346/only-amd-and-system-modules-are-supported-alongside-out), but I don't know how to modify *tsconfig.json* because it uses visual studio code and I use visual studio 2015.

can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose "none" in the TypeScript module type under the project (.csproj) properties -> TypeScript Build.

In Visual Studio 2015, the TypeScript Build tap seems to have an issue. When selecting "none", it does not always work. I got it to work by unloading the project and editing the following entry manually in the .csproj file.

```
<TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
<TypeScriptJSXEmit>None</TypeScriptJSXEmit>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
<TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
<TypeScriptModuleKind>None</TypeScriptModuleKind> <----- Set this value to None
<TypeScriptRemoveComments>False</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
```